# how can I increase my flutter web performance and how can i remove leggence in my flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

**I build  web application in flutter but the performance of my web application is too bad its not smooth its too much leggy what can I do to solve this problem**?
**give me suggestions**

i also try many solutions but these are not working for my flutter web i also make release of my web that's also leggy like my deub mode.
**my pub yaml file**

```
name: doctor appointment
description: Oriel Research Therapeutics online services.     

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  # firebase_auth: "^0.20.0+1"
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  # flutter_signin_button: ^1.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.4
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.6
  

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the Cupertino Icons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  flutter_custom_clippers: ^1.1.2
  responsive_builder: ^0.1.2
  # velocity_x: ^1.0.1
  velocity_x: ^2.6.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  provider: ^4.3.2
  footer: ^0.0.3
  # youtube_player_iframe: ^1.2.0+2
  carousel_slider: ^3.0.0
  youtube_plyr_iframe: ^2.0.0
  get: ^3.25.4
  package_info: ^0.4.3+4
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  equatable: ^2.0.0
  file_picker: 3.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.0
  # js: ^0.6.2
  page_transition: "^1.1.7+6"
  http:
  flutter_credit_card: ^2.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/logos/
    - assets/services/
    - assets/team/
    - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below Links. Helped me solve some performance issues by getting rid of page transitions.

https://medium.com/flutter/optimizing-performance-in-flutter-web-apps-with-tree-shaking-and-deferred-loading-535fbe3cd674

https://medium.com/flutter/improving-perceived-performance-with-image-placeholders-precaching-and-disabled-navigation-6b3601087a2b